# Adapt a react ImageSlider to NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have the following image slider in React, it's working as expected :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import item1 from "./../assets/images/items/1.jpg";
import item2 from "./../assets/images/items/2.gif";

const imgs = [item1, item2]; // Array of images

const ImageSlider = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0); // Initialize state to display the first image

  // Change image every 2 seconds
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrent((current) => (current + 1) % imgs.length); // Move to the next image, go back to the first image after the last
    }, 4000); // Change every 2 seconds

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval); // Clean up on unmount
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <img
        src={imgs[0]}
        className="w-full h-auto opacity-0"
        alt="placeholder"
      />
      {imgs.map((img, index) => (
        <img
          key={index}
          src={img}
          alt={`slide-img-${index}`}
          className={`absolute top-0 transition-opacity duration-1000 ease-in-out ${
            current === index ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"
          } w-full h-auto`}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageSlider;
```

but it's not working in NextJS, i adapted it a bit to fix the errors :

```
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const imgs = ["/images/1.jpg", "/images/2.gif", "/images/3.jpg"];
const ImageSlider = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0); // Initialize state to display the first image

  // Change image every 2 seconds
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrent((current) => (current + 1) % imgs.length); // Move to the next image, go back to the first image after the last
    }, 2000); // Change every 2 seconds

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval); // Clean up on unmount
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <img
        src={imgs[0]}
        className="w-full h-auto opacity-0"
        alt="placeholder"
      />
      {imgs.map((img, index) => (
        <img
          key={index}
          src={img}
          alt={`slide-img-${index}`}
          className={`absolute top-0 transition-opacity duration-1000 ease-in-out ${
            current === index ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"
          } w-full h-auto`}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageSlider;
```

I have tried to add 'use client' on top of the components and to modify the code to fix the errors my IDE was displaying, all the images in the array appears in the browser network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Next.js, you can't use React hooks directly in the top-level component. Instead, you can use the useEffect hook in the useEffect function of Next.js. Here's how you can modify your code to make it work in Next.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const imgs = ["/images/1.jpg", "/images/2.gif", "/images/3.jpg"];
const ImageSlider = () => {
const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setCurrent((current) => (current + 1) % imgs.length);
}, 2000);

return () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
};
}, []); // Empty dependency array to run effect only once

return (
<div className="relative">
  <img
    src={imgs[0]}
    className="w-full h-auto opacity-0"
    alt="placeholder"
  />
  {imgs.map((img, index) => (
    <img
      key={index}
      src={img}
      alt={`slide-img-${index}`}
      className={`absolute top-0 transition-opacity duration-1000 ease-in-out ${
        current === index ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"
      } w-full h-auto`}
    />
  ))}
</div>
  );
};

 export default ImageSlider;
```